# Node-sass error deploying to Heroku: ‘remove_cv’ !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, deployment, node-sass

I've created a Ruby on Rails app. It uses Rails for the backend and frontend. I'm using `.scss` files for styling.

Been getting this error when trying to deploy my app to Heroku:

```
/app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’
remote:        /app/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: note: suggested alternative: ‘remove_cv’
remote:                     !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
remote:                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~
remote:                                              remove_cv
```

Other info from error message:

```
gyp ERR! build error 
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_7da73fb3/node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1098-aws
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_7da73fb3/bin/node" "/tmp/build_7da73fb3/node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_7da73fb3/node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules/node-sass
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok 
remote:        Build failed with error code: 1
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
```

Have tried several ways to solve this and haven't yet. My Node version is v14.19.0

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Nail_The_Trail",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.3.0",
    "dart-sass": "^1.25.0",
    "node-sass": "6.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.49.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

Below are node-sass sections of my yarn.lock file (just noticed there appear to be two versions of node-sass in my yarn.lock file... perhaps this is a partial problem):

```
node-sass@6.0.1:
  version "6.0.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/node-sass/-/node-sass-6.0.1.tgz#cad1ccd0ce63e35c7181f545d8b986f3a9a887fe"
  integrity sha512-f+Rbqt92Ful9gX0cGtdYwjTrWAaGURgaK5rZCWOgCNyGWusFYHhbqCCBoFBeat+HKETOU02AyTxNhJV0YZf2jQ==
  dependencies:
    async-foreach "^0.1.3"
    chalk "^1.1.1"
    cross-spawn "^7.0.3"
    gaze "^1.0.0"
    get-stdin "^4.0.1"
    glob "^7.0.3"
    lodash "^4.17.15"
    meow "^9.0.0"
    nan "^2.13.2"
    node-gyp "^7.1.0"
    npmlog "^4.0.0"
    request "^2.88.0"
    sass-graph "2.2.5"
    stdout-stream "^1.4.0"
    "true-case-path" "^1.0.2"

node-sass@^4.13.0:
  version "4.14.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/node-sass/-/node-sass-4.14.1.tgz#99c87ec2efb7047ed638fb4c9db7f3a42e2217b5"
  integrity sha512-sjCuOlvGyCJS40R8BscF5vhVlQjNN069NtQ1gSxyK1u9iqvn6tf7O1R4GNowVZfiZUCRt5MmMs1xd+4V/7Yr0g==
  dependencies:
    async-foreach "^0.1.3"
    chalk "^1.1.1"
    cross-spawn "^3.0.0"
    gaze "^1.0.0"
    get-stdin "^4.0.1"
    glob "^7.0.3"
    in-publish "^2.0.0"
    lodash "^4.17.15"
    meow "^3.7.0"
    mkdirp "^0.5.1"
    nan "^2.13.2"
    node-gyp "^3.8.0"
    npmlog "^4.0.0"
    request "^2.88.0"
    sass-graph "2.2.5"
    stdout-stream "^1.4.0"
    "true-case-path" "^1.0.2"
```

Here is my gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "2.6.1"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem "rails", "~> 6.0.3", ">= 6.0.3.4"
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem "pg"
# Use Puma as the app server
gem "puma", "~> 4.1"
# Use SCSS for stylesheets


# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem "webpacker", "~> 4.0"
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem "turbolinks", "~> 5"
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem "jbuilder", "~> 2.7"
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", ">= 1.4.2", require: false

gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

gem "omniauth", "~> 2.0.4"

gem "omniauth-facebook"

gem "omniauth-rails_csrf_protection", "~> 1.0"

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem "byebug", platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem "web-console", ">= 3.3.0"
  gem "listen", "~> 3.2"
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem "spring"
  gem "spring-watcher-listen", "~> 2.0.0"
  gem "pry", "~> 0.13.1"
  gem "pry-rails"
  gem "faker"
  gem "omniauth", "~> 2.0.4"
  gem "omniauth-facebook"
  gem "omniauth-rails_csrf_protection", "~> 1.0"
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem "capybara", ">= 2.15"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem "webdrivers"
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

My site looks fine on localhost, but trying to deploy to Heroku gives error shown above.

I believe I'm currently using yarn and npm so this could be a partial problem, but not sure if it's the main problem. Also fyi, I recently deleted my package-lock.json.

Not sure what to do for this error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with heroku providing a node 16.x by default, and node-sass not liking it, preferring a 14.x;
I was able to use 14.x by putting:

`"engines" : { "node": "14.19.1" },`

in package.json, then locally using that version (nvm install 14.19.1; nvm use 14.19.1), and, on heroku, by making sure that you add the nodejs buildpack before the ruby one (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#installed-binaries), which I did by

```
heroku buildpacks:remove heroku/rails
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/rails
```